# Can I use jQuery replaceWith only on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to jQuery. I want to know if I can use `replaceWith` only on the home page?

All of my pages contains div content. I want to replace that div just for the home page but the following code replaces all the content on all pages.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#content').replaceWith('');
  });
```

Comment: make this part of script inline in your home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

1. Only insert this script on the homepage.
2. Detect that you're on the homepage, and conditionally invoke `replaceWith`.

   - If your  homepage has a specific URL (e.g. `/`), do;

     ```
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
               jQuery('#content').replaceWith('');
           }
       });
     ```
   - Add a class or ID or something to the `body` element on the homepage;

     ```
       jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           if (document.body.id === 'home') {
               jQuery('#content').replaceWith('');
           }
       });
     ```

p.s., I don't see why you can't use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove) rather than `replaceWith` in this circumstance.

Comment: beacause I am inserting around 15 divs with the replaceWith which I havent pasted here.

Comment: @Nick: aha, that makes sense. Both of the options I provided obviously still apply, the optional use of `remove()` was just an aside ;).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just use an if condition to hide the element like this:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var current_page_url = window.location.href;
    var hide_element_page = 'string unique to hide element page';

    if(current_page_url.indexOf(hide_element_page)){
        $(“#content “).hide();
    }
});
```